# How to change UITableViewCell Separator to custom one?

Tags: ios, uitableview

[image]

I download this app from AppStore and I think it's UITableViewCell's separator looks great.

And I want to change mime to this, but I dont know how to change the separator to custom one.

Is this an image just added to background ?So help me with this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is still the case but a year ago only way to do this was to add a custom separator view to the top (or bottom) of each cell.view. More on this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1375081/653513

Comment: I think this an image set as `backgroundView` to the cell.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom separator by applying a `UIImageView` to the bottom of every `UITableViewCell`.

and set the separator to `UITableViewCellSeperatorStyleNone`:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Comment: Can you show me some simple code about "You can create a custom separator by applying a UIImageView to the bottom of every UITableViewCell."? Thank you!