# UITableviewcell spacing between cells

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am creating `UITableView` cells dynamically and adding three labels on to it.I made my table as transparent by **opaque no and clearcolor**.
But the cells are being shown without spaces.I need to give space between cells.
Actually if i load a custom `UITableViewCell` from the xib file the space comes automatically. How to solve this issue?

Comment: are you creating UITableView and using its delegate methods to create cells?

Comment: Tableview i added through IB.cell is created using cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: make some difference between row height and cell height...

Answer (score 5):

#### UITableView with custom spacing

You can do this by cheating the tableView cell. By default you can only specify a single line, etched line or none so here is an alternative. You'll need to override the tableView delegate method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Calculate your cell height with its contents, margin/padding/line width and return it. Set the background color of the cell to `[UIColor clearColor]` and make your table background the desired color for your separator. Subclass UITableViewCell and attach a backgroundContainerView and make it the desired background color for your cell. Attach all the subview to that backgroundContainerView.

Finally, in the UITableViewCell subclass implement

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
```

Here you should layout the subviews with the container view as if that is the whole cell.

Comment: Will this work if built-in swipe-to-delete is used? I created a custom UITableViewCell layout with a transparent piece at the bottom but the Delete Gesture is visible [above it](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xnut7d460fi1nu4/IMG_2367.png).

Answer (score 1):

In UITableView you have 2 properties : `separatorStyle` and `separatorColor`. Use them maybe your separator color is **clearcolor** so try and change it.

Comment: i cannot use like this because i have a background image for tableview i need to show that image between cells.

Comment: You need to show the image between the cells meaning there is a whole background for the UITableViewCell or is it that each cell has its own specific background ?

Comment: Add number of row 1 in one section and number of sections as the number of elements in your array ....

Comment: i need to give background for cell..every cell is having same background.In result i should get a cell with background yellow inside that three labels and then a space  then another cell of same kind.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is due to the difference in height in TableView and Custom cell. Set the cell height in heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate.