# How to draw 1px line using BezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing, uibezierpath

I have following code to draw horizontal line:

```
UIBezierPath *topLine = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [topLine moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, topMargin + lineHeight * 2.0f)];
    [[self getTopSeparatorLineColor] setStroke];
    topLine.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    [topLine addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(rect.size.width, topMargin + lineHeight * 2.0f)];
    [topLine stroke];
```

It works, but line is "fat". I want to draw line just like UITableView separator..

Is it possible with UIBezierPath?

Comment: Perhaps `0.5`? A `lineWidth` of `1.0f` is (on retina devices) two pixels wide.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference

Comment: Should have made _some_ difference. lol. 0.25f?

Comment: 0.25f looks better, but I want to know how to make this properly without guessing numbers..

Comment: I guess if I have to use "magic" number - I need to know how to determine what this number is. Perhaps using some kind of API to get conversion?

Comment: If you want it to be identical, you might want to specify no separator, and then [draw your own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374990/how-to-customize-tableview-separator-in-iphone), and then you can ensure that both the separator and your new line are identically rendered.

Answer (score 1):

As Apple UIBezierPath Class Reference says:

> @property(nonatomic) CGFloat lineWidth
>
> The line width defines the thickness of the receiver's stroked path. A
>   **width of 0** is interpreted as the thinnest line that can be rendered on
>   a particular device.

So simply do it and you will always get 1px width:

```
topLine.lineWidth = 0.0f;
```

Comment: Had to take answer away. Just tried this - line not drawn at all. Not in Simulator, not on real device

Comment: Sure. I've got no chance to try it on my own yesterday but I remember that it worked in the past... Apple official reference lies at now?

Comment: Seems like it does. Or my eyes lying, they don't see the line :)