# Show custom separator UIView in table cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

hello I want to show a custom separator line with the same color and height of like default table separator. I am using Dynamic Prototype Table. I have put `UIView` from interface builder to my cell and set its height to 1px and setup an outlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var separatorLineUIView: UIView!
```

then I don't know what should I write here in  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProductRequestTableViewCell
           cell.separatorLineUIView
```

and also want to set its color and height to default table separator line so that it shows same for all the devices

Comment: what the problem u faced

Comment: i think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406014/how-to-customize-uitableview-separator-when-the-cells-got-a-custom-height

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I am asking how to show the separaterline

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set its height as `0.5`, not `1` in interface builder.

Because views' size is measured in points, and currently we have 2 pixels per point for retina screens and 3 pixels (which is downsampled) per point for retina HD screens.

And if you want to do it better, you can set separator's height to be equal to `1.0 / UIScreen.mainScreen().scale`

Comment: but first could you tell me how to show a separaterline. it is not coming up in my tableview