# How to set Separator style for UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone

how to change Separator Style for UITableView expandable cell. I am using Custom Tableview Class for that.

Comment: Can not understand question properly. please add more detail. you can set separator style using `yourTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine` or `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` or `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched`

Comment: Please search before you post your questions. Your question is a very basic task which was answered very often on this site. For example have a look at this: [Custom Separator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374990/how-to-customize-tableview-separator-in-iphone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potentially add a UIView as a separator of your own that has an autoresizing mask set to keep it stuck to the bottom.

`tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;`

Then in your custom UITableViewCell subclass

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor myColour]; // do cell setup in here


        UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, self.contentView.bounds.size.height - 1.0f, self.contentView.bounds.size.width, 1.0f)];
        lineView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
        lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor myOtherColour];

        [self.contentView addSubview:lineView];
}

return self;
```

}

If you really want to do it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can, but I wouldn't recommend it

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

      if (!cell)
      {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor myColour]; // do cell setup in here


        UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, cell.contentView.bounds.size.height - 1.0f, cell.contentView.bounds.size.width, 1.0f)];
        lineView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
        lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor myOtherColour];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:lineView];
      }

  // rest of your cell for row code here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
```

Comment: I tried it but it just change my main tableview not to expandable cell.

Comment: `expandable cell` or `expandable section`.?