# Create custom separator in Swift Table View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create a UILabel that is in between two cells,like how the table separator is presented.

Does Swift allow this with its built in functions for UITableView?

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the section headers
Check
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/table_views/adding_headers_and_footers_to_table_sections

Comment: Ooo good point. Did not think of doing it that way. Would be a pain to create new sections  dynamically. Nonetheless, this is a good way of doing it, if the table separator isn't viable.

Comment: Custom separator view handling for tableview on iOS are tricky...
You could also have a custom cell "SeparatorTableViewCell" and return 2x cellCount on number of cells and return the separator cell for every odd cell, and the current cell for every even cell

Comment: @Chris That's the other workaround I see... if you need custom separators for every cell.
Or add the "separator" to your custom cell and avoid using the separator as suggested:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374990/how-to-customize-tableview-separator-in-iphone

Comment: Thanks! I'll try the section headers way.